# Going through the source code for the prelude brings up weirdness

Tags: haskell, ghc, standard-library

I was looking for the definition of `seq` and came across this weirdness. Why do all these functions have the same/similar definitions?

```
seq :: a -> b -> b
seq = let x = x in x

inline :: a -> a
inline = let x = x in x    

lazy :: a -> a
lazy = let x = x in x
```

There are many more with this definition in the source code. What's going on?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What's going on is that these functions cannot be implemented in Haskell, but they should appear in the docs. Since `haddock` needs a syntactically correct (and well-typed) definition for each signature, the source must contain dummy definitions. Further, at the point where they are defined (in the `ghc-prim` package), `error` (and hence `undefined`) are not yet available, so the more obvious `seq = error "Not implementable in Haskell"` can't be used, thus the circular definition.

Comment: Is there a reason `error` *can't* be defined earlier than `seq` and friends?

Comment: `error` is defined as `throw (ErrorCall message)`, so for that you need the `Exception` mechanism and `Typeable`. It could be defined outside the`Exception` framework, directly using the `raise#` primitive, as far as I know, but it's nicer to have it fit in with the other `Exception`s. So to keep `ghc-prim` small, that only provides `raise#`, the more elaborate stuff goes into `base`. In short, it _could_ be defined earlier, but it's just not as nice, and there's no good reason to do it, the `GHC.Prim` source would be an unused dummy anyway.

Answer (score 9):

These definitions are a ruse: they're provided primitively by the GHC runtime. It turns out that the infinite loop `let x = x in x` can be given any type, so it's as good a ruse definition as any.