# Optimizing partial computation in Haskell

Tags: optimization, haskell, ghc

I'm curious how to optimize this code :

```
fun n = (sum l, f $ f0 l, g $ g0 l)
  where l = map h [1..n]
```

Assuming that `f`, `f0`, `g`, `g0`, and `h` are all costly, but the creation and storage of `l` is extremely expensive.

As written, `l` is stored until the returned tuple is fully evaluated or garbage collected.  Instead, `length l`, `f0 l`, and `g0 l` should all be executed whenever any one of them is executed, but `f` and `g` should be delayed.

It appears this behavior could be fixed by writing :

```
fun n = a `seq` b `seq` c `seq` (a, f b, g c)
  where
    l = map h [1..n]
    a = sum l
    b = inline f0 $ l
    c = inline g0 $ l
```

Or the very similar :

```
fun n = (a,b,c) `deepSeq` (a, f b, g c)
  where ...
```

We could perhaps specify a bunch of internal types to achieve the same effects as well, which looks painful.  Are there any other options?

Also, I'm obviously hoping with my `inline`s that the compiler fuses `sum`, `f0`, and `g0` into a single loop that constructs and consumes `l` term by term.  I could make this explicit through manual inlining, but that'd suck.  Are there ways to explicitly prevent the list `l` from ever being created and/or compel inlining?  Pragmas that produce warnings or errors if inlining or fusion fail during compilation perhaps?

As an aside, I'm curious about why `seq`, `inline`, `lazy`, etc. are all defined to by `let x = x in x` in the Prelude.  Is this simply to give them a definition for the compiler to override?

Comment: In response to the last question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8654407/1011995

Comment: Are `f0` and `g0` entirely arbitrary, or can they be written in terms of `foldr`?

Comment: Wouldn't a simple fold with an (a,b,c)-accumulator suffice here?

Comment: My answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409138/haskell-scan-through-a-list-and-apply-a-different-function-for-each-element/9411461#9411461 addresses exactly this.

Comment: Ahh yes, you cannot do much without `f0` and `g0` taking the right form.  I'd vaguely envisioned them both iterating over `l` while editing a vector that summarizes some information from `l`, probably both defined in terms of `Data.Vector.accum`, not sure `Data.Vector` can fuse two `accum` calls.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be sure, the only way is to do it yourself. For any given compiler version, you can try out several source-formulations and check the generated core/assembly/llvm byte-code/whatever whether it does what you want. But that could break with each new compiler version.

If you write

```
fun n = a `seq` b `seq` c `seq` (a, f b, g c)
  where
    l = map h [1..n]
    a = sum l
    b = inline f0 $ l
    c = inline g0 $ l
```

or the `deepseq` version thereof, the compiler might be able to merge the computations of `a`, `b` and `c` to be performed in parallel (not in the concurrency sense) during a single traversal of `l`, but for the time being, I'm rather convinced that GHC doesn't, and I'd be surprised if JHC or UHC did. And for that the structure of computing `b` and `c` needs to be simple enough.

The only way to obtain the desired result portably across compilers and compiler versions is to do it yourself. For the next few years, at least.

Depending on `f0` and `g0`, it might be as simple as doing a strict left fold with appropriate accumulator type and combining function, like the famous average

```
data P = P {-# UNPACK #-} !Int {-# UNPACK #-} !Double

average :: [Double] -> Double
average = ratio . foldl' count (P 0 0)
  where
    ratio (P n s) = s / fromIntegral n
    count (P n s) x = P (n+1) (s+x)
```

but if the structure of `f0` and/or `g0` doesn't fit, say one's a left fold and the other a right fold, it may be impossible to do the computation in one traversal. In such cases, the choice is between recreating `l` and storing `l`. Storing `l` is easy to achieve with explicit sharing (`where l = map h [1..n]`), but recreating it may be difficult to achieve if the compiler does some common subexpression elimination (unfortunately, GHC does have a tendency to share lists of that form, even though it does little CSE). For GHC, the flags `fno-cse` and `-fno-full-laziness` can help avoiding unwanted sharing.

Comment: Ahh, interesting point about the left vs. right fold!  I'm slightly confused about your CSE point though.  Are you simply observing that CSE can create this problem when you try to code around it naively?

Comment: If it's cheaper to recreate the list than to store it, you would write e.g. `f0 (map h [1 .. n])` and `g0 (map h [1 .. n])`. But the compiler may eliminate the common subexpression `map h [1 .. n]` and share it between the computations. Preventing that, if it's undesirable, is not as straightforward as the opposite, sharing a subexpression (which is done if you bind it to a name, `where l = map h [1 .. n]`). Basically, yes, CSE can introduce that problem, and it may be harder to work around.